# FF Mobile keyup/keydown keycode not working

Tags: android, jquery, firefox, mobile

recently I found that for some reason in Firefox Mobile for Android, the key/keyCode/which/charCode is not returning correctly using jQuery. Does there is any way to fix it?

Im using this code to test

https://jsfiddle.net/pr3ff3jn/8/

```
<input type="text" id="keyup">
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<div id="result3"></div>

<hr>
<input type="text" id="keydown">
<div id="result4"></div>
<div id="result5"></div>
<div id="result6"></div>
<div id="result7"></div>

<hr>
<input type="text" id="keypress">
<div id="result8"></div>
<div id="result9"></div>
<div id="result10"></div>
```

```
$("#keyup").on("keyup", function(ev){
    $("#result").html("key value: " + ev.key)
  $("#result1").html("keyCode value: " + ev.keyCode)
  $("#result2").html("which value: " + ev.which)
  $("#result3").html("charCode value: " + ev.charCode)
  console.log(ev)
})

$("#keydown").on("keydown", function(ev){
    $("#result4").html("key value: " + ev.key)
  $("#result5").html("keyCode value: " + ev.keyCode)
  $("#result6").html("which value: " + ev.which)
  $("#result7").html("charCode value: " + ev.charCode)
  console.log(ev)
})

$("#keypress").on("keypress", function(ev){
    $("#result8").html("key value: " + ev.key)
  $("#result9").html("keyCode value: " + ev.keyCode)
  $("#result10").html("which value: " + ev.which)
  $("#result11").html("charCode value: " + ev.charCode)
  console.log(ev)
})
```

Typing normal characters (a-Z or backspace), for me returns the following data:

```
key value: Unidentified
keyCode value: 0
which value: 0
charCode value: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a conflict with mobile touch input, I've experienced something like that in my past. Try using a mobile porting of jquery such as jquery mobile